# ¿Cómo optimizar las restauraciones de base de datos en SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

**Buenas tardes,**

Me han encomendado averiguar si es factible implementar la habilitación de cambios que sugiere el siguiente mensaje al hacer restauraciones de backup mediante una solución de backup en un servidor SQL Server 2008.

```
*"Instant file initialization is not enabled, please enable this feture for 
improved restore performance. However, the restore operation will continue. 
See Microsoft documentation for details on enabling the database instant 
file initialization feature on the SQL Server."*
```

Internet me arroja documentación tras documentación, pero no entiendo mucho del tema, me interesa que tan seguro es realizar esto de cara a la seguridad de información y cuales serían los pasos para hacerlo.

Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que nada, veamos cual es el comportamiento que buscas modificar. SQL Server, en ciertas operaciones requiere allocar más espacio físico del que dispones, tipicamente son las siguientes opciones:

- Crear un database.
- Agregar archivos de datos o de log a un database.
- Incrementar el espacio de archivo de datos/log (incluyendo el AUTOGROW)
- Restaurar un database.

Por defecto, todo nuevo espacio que se incorpora al manejo del motor, se inicializa a cero. Es decir cada byte reservado se sobreescribe con el valor `0x00`. Es decir, por ejemplo en el caso de un `restore` de una base de datos de 500 Gb, el motor en primer lugar "solicita" el espacio al sistema operativo y luego se encarga de sobreescribir todos los bytes de esos 500gb para dejarlos en cero, y eso antes de siquiera empezar a recuperar el backup.

#### ¿Cual es el sentido de inicializar el contenido?

Mayor seguridad. Vamos un poco más atrás, al eliminar cualquier archivo, el sistema operativo, no lo elimina físicamente sino que simplemente "marca" el espacio ocupado por él, como disponible, por lo que ese espacio podría ser reclamado por cualquier proceso que lo requiera. Imaginemos un archivo "sensitivo" que tiene incluso unos permisos bien restrictivos, al borrarlo, el espacio se libera, pero los `bytes` siguen estando ahí, con herramientas adecuadas, eventualmente podríamos recuperar todo el contenido original. La idea de "inicializar" el espacio allocado por el SQL Server va justamente en el sentido de no poder leer de ninguna forma ese contenido "sensible".

La idea es buena y razonable, pero volviendo al ejemplo de la restauración de una base de 500gb, inicializar esos 500gb no es algo gratuito, lleva tiempo y además, hay que pensar que luego el RESTORE en caso de ser exitoso terminará a su vez sobreescribiendo completamente el espacio allocado, es decir estamos duplicando la escritura. Acá entra a jugar la configuración de **"Instant file initialization"**. Básicamente lo se hace es decirle al SQL Server que no inicialice el espacio alocado con la consiguiente (y muy importante) mejora de performance.

#### Consideraciones de seguridad

El impacto de configurar **"Instant file initialization"** en la seguridad es sencillo de entender. Cualquier operación que reserve espacio físico no inicializará el mismo, por consiguiente, un usuario de SQL con permisos adecuados podría eventualmente "espiar" información sensible que hubiéramos eliminado:

```
-- Enable DBCC trace flag 3604
DBCC TRACEON(3604)
GO

-- Dump out a page somewhere in the data file
-- A hex dump is working here
DBCC PAGE (TestDatabase, 1, 1000, 2)
GO
```

Fuente: [Improving SQL Server Performance by using Instant File Initialization](http://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2014/02/18/improving-sql-server-performance-by-using-instant-file-initialization/)

Con el comando anterior obtendríamos el contenido completo de un página del database `TestDatabase`, si ésta fuera una página del espacio allocado sin inicializar posiblemente estaríamos viendo directamente el contenido de un archivo eliminado (lo que sería hacer un "undelete").

#### Configuración del "Instant file initialization"

Es relativamente sencillo.

1. En primer lugar deberemos determinar en el servidor, la cuenta con que se inicia el servicio del SQL Server.
2. Luego deberemos agregarle a esta cuenta el permiso adecuado, el cual se configurará "Directiva de seguridad Local" (`secpol.msc`)

   - Ir a Directivas Locales -> Asignación de derechos de usuario
   - Buscar la directiva: "Realizar tareas de mantenimiento del volumen"
   - Agregar la cuenta del SQL Server.
   - Reiniciar SQL Server

Nota: es posible y hasta recomendable, darle permiso directamente al grupo de los Administradores de SQL.

#### Otras consideraciones

- Motor: Disponible desde SQL Server 2005
- SO: Disponible desde Microsoft Windows XP Professional, Windows Server 2003 o superior. El SO debe soportar la API [`SetFileValidData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365544(VS.85).aspx)
- El sistema de archivos debe ser NTFS
- La cuenta que inicia el servicio de SQL Server, debe tener el privilegio **SE_MANAGE_VOLUME_NAME**
- Solo para los archivos de datos. Los archivos de LOG siempre se inicializarán, el proceso de "crash recovery" necesita que así sea.
- Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) tiene que estar deshabilitado
- El Trace flag 1806 que deshabilita el "instant file initialization", obviamente debe estar en "off".

#### Enlaces de interés:

- [Improving SQL Server Performance by using Instant File Initialization](http://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2014/02/18/improving-sql-server-performance-by-using-instant-file-initialization/)
- [Database File Initialization](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-instant-file-initialization)
- [Instant Initialization – What, Why and How?](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/instant-initialization-what-why-and-how/)
- [How and Why to Enable Instant File Initialization](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_pfe_blog/2009/12/22/how-and-why-to-enable-instant-file-initialization/)

Comment: Gracias, Con respecto al ´SE_MANAGE_VOLUME_NAME´ ¿Este privilegio se asigna automáticamente?. Leía también sobre los puntos de seguridad y la posibilidad de que estos puedan ser leídos por otros usuarios SQL,que todo esto se puede evitar con la Lista de Control de Acceso Discrecional (DACL) en el archivo. ¿Que tan necesario es esta herramienta?

Comment: El privilegio SE_MANAGE_VOLUME_NAME, es simplemente el que menciono en la configuración ("Realizar tareas de mantenimiento del volumen"). El uso de DACL es fundamental, pero va más allá de este tema, un data `data file` sin los permisos adecuados, puede ser observado por cualquier usuario, el cual podría ver tanto información "eliminada" como es el caso de tu pregunta o información de las tablas que tampoco debería ver. Saludos.